# change default pythonpath

Tags: python

I have two python installation. One is installed in default location and other is installed in my home directory. I am using home directory python installation. I am facing problem about pythonpath. When I run sys.path on 2nd python installation it gives me paths for libraries of default python installation

eg.

2nd python is installed in `/home/python2.6.1`
now when i use `sys.path` it gives me

`/lib/python2.6/lib-old, /lib/python2.6/lib-dynload` etc.

instead of

```
/home/python2.6.1/lib/python2.6/lib-old, /home/python2.6.1/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload
```

how can I change path for my python installation in home directory

Comment: by changing PYTHONPATH it will still have those libraries in PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your libraries are installed in /lib or the interpreter has been configured to scan /lib for libraries. You need to recompile Python and give the configure script another prefix for the libraries.

But, this isn't what I would do. I'd install virtualenv and start managing my Python versions that way. This is what I do actually ;) Clean and simple!

Comment: Is it possible without installing virualenv and without recompiling python, like by making some changes to search module of python or site.py